# How can I enable AVD buttons and controls in Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Here's a screenshot from Android Studio 0.5 that has the controls.
I want these virtual controls to be visible in Android Studio 1.0.1 as well.

[Screenshot showing the controls](http://i58.tinypic.com/1gcag.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change settings in your avd

Comment: Which setting(s)?
Change it to what?

Comment: Any questions? What do you mean? Did you check my link?